# Performance Testing in Java (API calls)

Tags: java, api, software-testing

I want to test my API. My API would include images that would be served on a particular device. I  wanted to make automated calls in the range of 100s.

I am using Eclipse IDE and using the JavaImageIO library for image processing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use JMeter for performance  testing. It is an open source project and it can be easily integrated with your test plan. You can use this tool to check the performance of your appplicaton and automating calls.